# JSDoc: how to declare a closure variable (available in a nested function from outer scope)?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Suppose that I have a nested function and want to document the fact that it's using a variable from outer scope. What annotation do I use in JSDoc?

Example:

```
var Constructor = function () {
    var externalVariable = "foo";

    /**
     * This method does whatever it does.
     *
     * @?????? {string} externalVariable - closure variable from outer scope 
     */
    this.method = function() {
        console.log(externalVariable);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the correct approach, but I'd document the external variable and make a reference to it in the exposed method.

```
var Constructor = function () {

    /**
     * @private
     * @alias externalVariable
     * @type {String}
     */
    var externalVariable = "foo";

    /**
     * This method does whatever it does.
     *
     * @see externalVariable
     */
    this.method = function() {
        console.log(externalVariable);
    }

}
```